# What pokemon do the NPCs use when allied for multi-battles?

Tags: nintendo-ds, pokemon-fifth-generation

On the battle subway you can ally with an NPC (for multi battle and super-multi battle), and tell them to focus on Attack, Defense, or Mixed. What sort of pokemon am I signing myself up for with the various options? Does the game take into account the pokemon I've selected for the subway or is it completely random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a list of possible choices on Serebii:
[List of Offensive, Defensive, and Balanced NPC Pokemon](http://www.serebii.net/blackwhite/subwaymulti.shtml)